# How to access cross table columns in iron python script

Tags: ironpython, crosstab, spotfire

I am trying to access the columns in a cross table visualization in an iron python script but i couldn't find a way to do that. I would like to access the columns just as i can access the columns of a table visualization - table.TableColumns
Also i need to get the columns that are created by custom expression and not added to the data table.
Tnx.